# Detecting an opened internet address in vbscript

Tags: browser, vbscript

Is there a way, using vbscript, to detect if a certain address is opened on any internet browser? I'm only a beginner in vbs so I don't really understand so much of it.

Comment: No; that is not easily possible.

Comment: But would there be any way for vbscript to scan for a certain text using an opened window's titlebar?

Comment: 1) I don't think so (however, look at http://wasp.codeplex.com/) 2) That won't help for inactive browser tabs.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. You'd need to hook system level calls and that would need to be done in C/C++ if it was even possible at all.